# It's good to practice using try with resources without finally in Java

Tags: java, quarkus, try-with-resources

I am working with microservices in Quarkus (Java Framework). I have doubts about the closing of connections using `try`-with-resources. According to the documentation if we have an `AutoCloseable` object it should close the connection and clean up the objects. Is this really true or is it recommended to continue using `finally` to close connections?

```
package com.tmve.subscriber.repository;
import io.agroal.api.AgroalDataSource;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class FindPrepaidSubscriberICCIDRepository {


    public HashMap<String,String> getResources(AgroalDataSource defaultDataSource, String movil){
        HashMap<String,String> map= new HashMap<>();
        try(Connection conn= defaultDataSource.getConnection();
            CallableStatement stm = conn.prepareCall("{call PKG_LCL_CUENTA.B_DATOS_CLIENTE_X_MOVIL(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}"))
        {
            Integer qmovil=Integer.valueOf(movil);
            stm.setInt(1,qmovil);
            stm.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
            stm.registerOutParameter(3,Types.VARCHAR);
            stm.registerOutParameter(4,Types.VARCHAR);
            stm.registerOutParameter(5,Types.VARCHAR);
            stm.registerOutParameter(6,Types.VARCHAR);
            stm.registerOutParameter(7,Types.VARCHAR);
            stm.registerOutParameter(8,Types.VARCHAR);
            stm.registerOutParameter(9,Types.VARCHAR);
            stm.registerOutParameter(10,Types.VARCHAR);
            stm.registerOutParameter(11,Types.VARCHAR);
            stm.registerOutParameter(12,Types.VARCHAR);
            stm.registerOutParameter(13,Types.VARCHAR);
            stm.registerOutParameter(14,Types.INTEGER);
            stm.registerOutParameter(15,Types.INTEGER);
            stm.registerOutParameter(16,Types.VARCHAR);
            stm.registerOutParameter(17,Types.VARCHAR);
            stm.registerOutParameter(18,Types.INTEGER);
            stm.registerOutParameter(19,Types.VARCHAR);
            stm.registerOutParameter(20,Types.VARCHAR);
            stm.registerOutParameter(21,Types.VARCHAR);
            stm.registerOutParameter(22,Types.VARCHAR);
            stm.registerOutParameter(23,Types.VARCHAR);
            stm.registerOutParameter(24,Types.VARCHAR);
            stm.registerOutParameter(25,Types.INTEGER);
            stm.registerOutParameter(26,Types.INTEGER);
            stm.registerOutParameter(27,Types.VARCHAR);
            stm.registerOutParameter(28,Types.VARCHAR);
            stm.registerOutParameter(29,Types.VARCHAR);

            stm.execute();

            map.put("P_CICCID",stm.getString(27));
            return map;

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            map.put("error_message",e.getMessage());
            return map;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement. Any object that implements java.lang.AutoCloseable, which includes all objects which implement java.io.Closeable, can be used as a resource. Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the `AutoCloseable` object you're working with has bugs with its `close()` method (which would prevent you from using `finally` *anyway*), using try-with-resources is preferred over `finally`.

The objective reason is [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html).

> An object that may hold resources (such as file or socket handles) until it is closed. The close() method of an AutoCloseable object is called automatically when exiting a try-with-resources block for which the object has been declared in the resource specification header. This construction ensures prompt release, avoiding resource exhaustion exceptions and errors that may otherwise occur.

With a `finally` block, you have to remember to keep track of what it is you opened and then be sure it's closed at the end of execution.  With a try-with-resources block, you're guaranteed that this will happen at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Try with resource should be the preferred way. For 2 reasons.

First, you can see what your resources are at a glance via the try definition. Second, you can't forget to close a resource. A finally, theoretically, can also be interrupted. Let's assume you have two resources open, in the finally you close both, but the first one you try closing throws an exception, now you're never closing the second one. Granted, it's a contrived example, but the finally could have more complex code and it might be easy to miss / forget the resource.